# Flutter Field 'replyMessage' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

I have reply class which will be filled with data when user try to reply a message other than that it's just null objects. And now it gives me following error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'replyMessage' has not been initialized.
```

`Code`

```
late ReplyMessage replyMessage;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then I check this `replyMessage` when user click on send button like this (error line commented):

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
        _textEditingController.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
        setState(() {
            _validate = false;
            if(replyMessage.id != null) { // <-- error comes from this line
            sendMessage(userToken, _textEditingController.text, args.id, replyMessage.id);
            }
            else {
            sendMessage(userToken, _textEditingController.text, args.id, null);
            }
        });
        });
    });
    },
    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
    color: btnColor,
),
```

***Additionally here us my class code:***

```
class ReplyMessage {
  int? id;
  String? message;
  String? userName;

  ReplyMessage({
    required this.id,
    required this.message,
    required this.userName
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you define your field as late than you must initialize it in init method or direct assign value

```
late ReplyMessage replyMessage;
  @override
  void initState() {
replyMessage =  Assign some value here

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: How can I define it in initState?

Comment: It gives `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String?>' is not a subtype of type 'ReplyMessage' in type cast`

Comment: what value you are assigning

Comment: `replyMessage = {
      'id': null,
      'message': '',
      'userName': ''
    } as ReplyMessage;`

Comment: assign ReplyMessage()

Comment: yes this works now `replyMessage =  ReplyMessage(message: '', userName: '', id: null);` Thank you